# event.stopPropagation doesn't work for a modal('show')

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a ng-click at the same time on a `<ul>` (or on a `<tr>`) and on a button which is inside it.

I want to do something if I click on the line, and only show a bootstrap modal if I click on my button.

The problem is that for a `modal('show')` declared by the button code, the code of the line is still executed when my modal disappeared, even with an `event.stopPropagation()` in the button code.

Here is the code ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3drpkwpk/11/)):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="clickLine(item)">
        Just a test <button ng-click="clickButton(item, $event)">{{item}}</button><button ng-click="clickAlert(item, $event)">alert {{item}}</button>
        <div class="modal fade comment_{{item}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Test {{item}}
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$scope.clickLine = function(item) {
    alert('line : '+item);
};
$scope.clickButton = function(item, event) {
    angular.element('.comment_'+item).modal('show');
    event.stopPropagation();
};
$scope.clickAlert = function(item, event) {
    alert('Click alert: '+item);
    event.stopPropagation();
};
$scope.items = ['One', 'two', '3'];
```

Here when I click on the first button, the modal shows, and when I click outside in order to make it disappeared, `clickUl` code executes itself! Whereas a click on the second button only executes `clickAlert` code...

Any reason for that? A bootstrap bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in that [issue comment](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16056#issuecomment-78911403), the second event which is launched after the modal is closed is a complete new one because the modal is **in** the line, so the "click on line" event is launched if I click outside the modal to exit it ("backdrop").

The solution is to move the modal comments out of the first iteration ([full fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3drpkwpk/16/)):

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="clickLine(item)">
                Just a test <button ng-click="clickButton(item, $event)">{{item}}</button><button ng-click="clickAlert(item, $event)">alert {{item}}</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="modal fade comment_{{item}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Test {{item}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or without repeating the modal ([full fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3drpkwpk/17/)):

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="clickLine(item)">
                Just a test <button ng-click="clickButton(item, $event)">{{item}}</button><button ng-click="clickAlert(item, $event)">alert {{item}}</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade globalModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ng-controller="GlobalModalCtrl">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" ng-bind="globalModalService.title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" ng-bind="globalModalService.body">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$scope.clickButton = function(item, event) {
    globalModalService.show('Test title', 'Test '+item);
    event.stopPropagation();
};
```

With this handling of the global modal:

```js
.controller('GlobalModalCtrl', function(globalModalService, $scope) {
    $scope.globalModalService = globalModalService;
})
.factory('globalModalService', function() {
    var globalModalService = {
        body: null,
        title: null,
        show: function(title, body) {
            globalModalService.body = body;
            globalModalService.title = title;
            angular.element('.globalModal').modal('show');
        }
    };
    return globalModalService;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Click on modal**
i think your mistake is you given ng-click on ng-repeat . you have to give to its button . here is live code : https://jsfiddle.net/3drpkwpk/8/  
then don't use unnecessarily **event.stopPropagation()** it stop yours other html default event functions.

```
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="">

            Just a test 
  <button ng-click="clickButton(item, $event);clickUl(item)">{{item}}</button><button ng-click="clickAlert(item, $event);clickUl(item)">alert {{item}}</button>
            <div class="modal fade comment_{{item}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Test {{item}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: Actually, in my use case I **must** execute some code when I click on the line (here the `<li>` but in my real use case, it's a `<tr>` in a table), and only another code (showing a modal) when I click on my button... So your solution can't satisfy my use case unfortunately

Comment: you can stop some functionality when model visible by give it in if condition else your code go on here

Comment: I see what you mean, but the problem is that I can't do that as the `clickUl` method is executed **after** the modal has disappeared (what's really odd), so I can't test on its `visible` state...

Comment: sorry this new please it help you by god grace :: https://jsfiddle.net/3drpkwpk/10/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you could have a better implementation adding Angular Bootstrap module (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). You can create a modals with a method, even in stack.

It's really easy, just add the module, inject the $modal service and create an instance, which contains a promise. That promise can be used later to know when the modal has been dismissed/closed.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QLDFx3nmqSwD9M5Vcqob?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer David, but I don't really understand the relation with my problem... The problem I described is: if I have a line (`li` or `tr`) with a `ng-click` in it, and a `button` inside with a `ng-click` code, the button code will be executed and THEN the line code except if I specify `event.stopPropagation` (as in my example). This works **except** if I open a bootstrap modal, then the line code will be executed after my modal will close, even with an `event.stopPropagation`.

Comment: It's just a tidier way to get the same results. As said by another user here you shouldn't put the ng-click on the li, but on buttons. I just suggested using that plugin to easily get a tidier and more scalable solution.

Comment: It's not really the same result as what I'm expecting is to do an action if I click on a line, and popup a modal if I click on the button in the line but don't doing the action of the line. Actually, I'm in a table, and want to select the line if I click on it, and want to popup a modal if I click on the button at the end of my line.

Comment: Then you just need a stopPropagation on your table row click event listener.

Comment: Which doesn't work if I open a modal... As explained in my example, and the purpose of my question: `stopPropagation` doesn't work if I open a bootstrap modal.

Comment: It doesn't work because you didn't pass the event to the event listener.
Try this:
    <li ng-click="onClick($event, item)"></li>
    $scope.onClick = function(event, item) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // your code
    }

Comment: It's already what I have in the button code: see my `$scope.clickButton`. The code in `$scope.clickAlert` correctly works: it displays an alert, and `stopPropagation` forbids the `$scope.clickLine` to be executed. But `$scope.clickButton` doesn't manage to do that. The only difference between both is that my `$scope.clickButton` opens a bootstrap modal.

Comment: you need to stop the propagation first of all!!

Comment: I tried that here https://jsfiddle.net/3drpkwpk/12/ but nothing changed: when I click on the first button, it's still displaying first my modal, and when quitting executing the line code (display an alert message)

Comment: The problem wasn't the stopPropagation, but the modal on every row. This is not the way to do it and the reason I recommended using the angular-ui bootstrap module. Look at this: http://plnkr.co/edit/uWKkxYRpu8v4WOtOtZfq?p=preview
And please give me my point back.

Comment: Your plunkr doesn't include the code you show on your reply and moreover I still don't see the need of a promise in my use case...

Comment: Did you resolve it without iterating your items twice adding a lot of html to make many modals to be ready just in case?

Comment: Yes, in my final code I wrote my modal only once, and when I click on the button, I modify the content using `angular.element`

Comment: In your post marked as a solution you are doing this <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="clickLine(item)"> and then this <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="modal fade comment_{{item}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">, in other words you are iterating twice. So you are generating lots of useless html. It could work but it's not a good solution.

Comment: I edited my answer with the final code I used. I still don't really understand the promise usage in your answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73190/discussion-between-david-vartanian-and-anthony-o).